# Identify websocket client

Tags: websocket, dart

How I can identify a connection, and be sure of destination of a message? Like a chat with private message.

Actually, I have read the request header, and I saw a line with `sec-websocket-key`. There is a relation with what I'm asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The key is is part of the WebSocket handshake.

The websocket connection will send the HTTP cookies during the handshake, so if the user is authenticated with cookies, you can reuse that information.